# storing values in an array

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

So I am trying to work with arrays in MASM32 (came from C++) and its really getting annoying. I prototyped what I want in C++ and it looks like this:

```
void randomplaceShip()
{
    int toPlace = 3;
    srand(time(0));

    while (toPlace > 0)
    {
        int v1 = rand() % 12;
        int v2 = rand() % 12;

        if (dArray[v1][v2] != 'X' && v1 < 9)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                dArray[v1+i][v2] = 'X';
            }
            toPlace--;
        } 
    }
}
```

It places 3 ships on a 12x12 game board each 1 wide and 3 long. So far, in assembly, I store my array address in the `esi` register, and get a random number between 1-9 that I store in `rVal`. I am having trouble with storing an "X" at the right spot because there's no indexing like there is in C++. The array I am using in MASM32 is a byte array with 144 slots (for the 12x12 board).

```
lea esi, dArray
    mov eax, 11

    .while eax > 10
        invoke crt_rand
    .endw
    mov rVal1, eax

    mov eax, 11
    .while eax > 10
        invoke crt_rand
    .endw
    mov rVal2, eax

    movzx eax, byte ptr [esi+1*rVal1]    ;The problem
    mov eax, "x"                         ;is here
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here:

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [esi+1*rVal1]
```

Is reading from memory, not writing to it. The address is also incorrect; you're trying to read from the address formed by `esi` + *the address of* `rVal1` (`[x]` doesn't mean "use the value at `x` as the address". it simply means "use the address of `x` as the address").

Assuming that each element in your array is a byte, what you want is to store the value `'X'` at `OFFSET dArray + (rVal1 + i) * 12 + rVal2`, i.e. something like this:

```
mov eax, rVal1
add eax, i              ; eax = rVal1 + i
shl eax, 2              ; eax = (rVal1 + i) * 4
lea eax, [eax*2 + eax]  ; eax = ((rVal1 + i) * 4) * 3  
add eax, rVal2          ; eax = (rVal1 + i) * 12 + rVal2
mov byte ptr [dArray + eax], 'X'
```